# Is it possible for my Windows 10 to recognize GPU as CPU cores?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, cpu, gpu

I am trying to run many processes on different cores. The application I am running uses on CPU and no  GPU.

Is it possible to convert the graphics card to act like virtual CPU cores?
I just need the CPU cores. I have TITAN Xp which is almost 3000 to 4000 core.

Kindly, suggest me how my system can detect the GPU as CPU.

Comment: Absolutely not. Please learn about GPGPU if you want to harness your GPU’s power.

Comment: No. The GPU is not a general purpose CPU and lacks a large amount of control logic. It uses "stream processors" that are more suited to repeating the same (small) task across large datasets than diverse branching logic as supported by the main CPU. The CPU and GPU are entirely different beasts.

Answer (score 3):

The CPU and GPU are entirely different - with the GPU being designed to run specific tasks relevant to graphics - mainly very paralleled, simple instructions or handling specific algorythns - for this reason it can't function like a regular CPU.

In order to take advantage of the power of the GPU applications need to be specifically written (eg to use CUDA for NVIDIA) - and this is only appropriate for some tasks - eg password cracking, finding some hashes.